MacOS - how to allow spamming of Caps Lock?
I have a MacBook which disables Caps Lock if I continuously press it too fast. I capitalise characters by toggling Caps Lock and I really need the key to just perform normally. Is it possible to disable this feature?
The caps lock key does not respond when I tap it too fast. It either stays on or off and ghosts some taps, if I continuously press it very fast it just stays off.
I've already tried setting Key Repeat to off, to no avail.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What did you try setting to off? You need to be as specific as possible here. I also corrected the terrible title that suggested you're looking for the opposite.

I've turned off the Key Repeat setting.
